# How to get timeseries from Django model by date and by foreign key?

Tags: python, django, time-series

I have the following two models:

```py
class Station(models.Model):
   # fields of station

class StationReading(models.Model):
   station = models.ForeignKey(Station)
   speed = models.FloatField()
   time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to build a timeseries dataset that each row is a unique `time` field, each column is an existing `Station` (by id) and the values are `speed`. My expected output:

```
|       Date      | Station_1 | Station_2 | etc...
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|
| < some date 1>  | <speed of |<speed of  |
|                 | station 1>| station 2>|
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|
| < some date 2>  | <speed of |<speed of  |
|                 | station 1>| station 2>|
```

Performance is important here, as I have millions of `StationReading` objects. Is this possible solely using Django queries?

Comment: Created index on datetime field ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi the current database in production does not have datetime field index. But it can be created

Comment: then you must create index on datetimefield because it will be used more frequently in querying.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi makes sense, thanks. Any idea on how to produce this table as result?